# It is possible to join UK army in free time to participate to training, without going at war?

Tags: united-kingdom, training

How much would cost to join UK military training (if possible) just when I want to (holidays)? I mention that I don't have UK nationality, but I will complete my higher education degrees (looking forward to completing BSc and PhD in Mathematics) and get a citizenship and a job in UK. What branches of army can be accessed this way and what should I do to be eligible for this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want this without any chance of going to war if war (or other military action) is declared?  I can't imagine any country would allow that.

Comment: Being me the one who pays, why not?

Comment: coz it's not a martial arts club maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been mentioned, there are [University Officer Training Corps](http://www.army.mod.uk/UOTC/28464.aspx) units spread around the country. These units are intended to act as a gateway for university students to get leadership training prior to moving into the regular or TA forces as officers. Sometimes, individuals may volunteer for secondment to regular forces, and even deployment, but the only time the whole unit would be activated would be under a national conscription.

You will get paid for one night a week and couple of weekends a term, plus week long camps and opportunities for other training (parachuting, expeditions, etc) during the university holiday periods.

As far as I can recall - membership is open to Commonwealth citizens.

However, there is a selection process, and limited intake per year. Competition is very stiff, and you're more likely to be accepted if you show intention to continue after graduation in either the regular or territorial forces.

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly join the TA (Army Reserves)  it would depend on what country you come from if you can or not.

Comment: Many universities have a [UOTC](http://www.army.mod.uk/UOTC/28464.aspx), which is group B TA (= not sent abroad to fight). It's one night a week and many weekends though, not to your schedule.

Comment: The TA will require you to do training when *they* want, and TA members can be (and have been) sent overseas on active duty.

Comment: While not the UK, in the USA most of the troops sent to Iraq came from the Reserves. Quite a few people were shocked to learn that their one weekend a month enlistment turned into a 13 month deployment in a hellhole in the middle east real fast.

Comment: @Dunk I know some one I know was a RSM in the TA Signals Regiment went out to Iraq.